# How to set Window position for different DataTemplates

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm

How can I set position for MainWindow depend on View that window is currently presenting?

I'm using DataTemplates to pick correct View and implement it as Content to MainWIndow.

for e.g.

```
<ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LoginViewM.Content}" Value="">
                            <Setter Property="Content">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SP:SplashViewModel/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LoginViewM.Content}" Value="Admin">
                            <Setter Property="Content">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <EE:EmployeeViewModel/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
```

Depends on which view is implemented, I would like to set MainWindow position. I could bind `Top` and `Left` to property in main ViewModel but the problem is with `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` of the View. I'm not able to get it from ViewModel.

In WinForm I was using `SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width/Height` and in MVVM?

```
_Left = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width - ActualWidth
```

Thank you very much for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the `MainWindow` to `Width` and `Height` properties in your View Model. Here is an example:

```
private double _WindowWidth = 500;

public double WindowWidth
{
    get { return _WindowWidth; }
    set 
    { 
        _WindowWidth = value;

        //INotifyPropertyChanged stuff.
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

And on your `View`:

```
Width="{Binding WindowWidth}"
```

Using the `WindowWidth` property, you can have another property for `Left` and `Top`.

```
private double _WindowLeft = 150;

public double WindowLeft
{
    get { return _WindowLeft ; }
    set 
    { 
        _WindowLeft = value;

        //INotifyPropertyChanged stuff.
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Just like before, you can bind to the property:

```
Left="{Binding WindowLeft}"
```

The benefit of this method is that you now have access to the Windows `Left`, `Top`, `Width`, and `Height` properties in your **View Model**. Therefore, you can execute your logic that will resize/relocate your **View** in your constructor, or where it's needed in the View Model.

Consider putting these properties in a **base class**, therefore all your View Models can inherit from the class without having to implement the properties.